# Query in Firebase with equalTo method

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

I want to order by timeStamp the comments inside the `comments` node, get the last 15 messages starting with `KsBazxx0bew6UOfUI5J` which is a child of the `comments` node. I´m trying to get the comments using the following code:

```
FirebaseRef.orderByChild("timeStamp").startAt(commentID).limitToLast(15).addChildEventListener(likeOrCommentsListener);
```

unfortunetly I'm not able to get any information, which makes me think that the query is wrong.
How can I  get the messages using those restrictions?

Comment: Can you show the child event listener?. It has 5 callback method and at least the return the value which is passed in `startAt()`, in method `onChildAdded()`, if there are no other results.

Comment: show how you are getting the firebase ref.

Comment: you can't use startAt on ID , you can use it on value of key under ID

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're ordering by timestamp, you need to pass in the value of the timestamp where you want to start the query:

```
FirebaseRef.orderByChild("timeStamp").startAt(150317519355)...
```

If there may be multiple items with the same timestamp, you can **additionally** specify that the query should start at a specific key:

```
FirebaseRef.orderByChild("timeStamp").startAt(150317519355, "KsBazxx0bew6UOfUI5J")...
```

Comment: thanks for such a quick response, I only have a little problem, it says that the timeStamp `150317519355` is too large to add it i the `startAt()`, or am I doing something wrong? Many thanks

Comment: I copied the value from your screenshot (next time post the JSON as text please). I might have made a typo, although I don't see it. If you can store a value as a number, you should be able to query it since [`startAt()` takes a `double`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43203910/how-to-create-negative-firebase-timestamp-in-swift/43394905#43394905). If you keep having problems, update your question with the code that reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 DatabaseReference databaseReference = Firebase.getInstance().getReference();
Query lastQuery = databaseReference.child("comments").orderByChild("timeStamp").limitToLast(15);
lastQuery.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
       //use this dataSnapshot
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        //Handle possible errors.
    }
});
```