# How to convert Firebase Server time value in to NSDate

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase

```
NSDate *today = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:(NSInteger)[FIRServerValue timestamp]/1000];
```

I am use above code to convert `[FIRServerValue timestamp]` into `NSDate` in my ios app. But I could't get the expected result. It returns `1970-03-13 11:37:47 +0000`. So how to get current server time using `[FIRServerValue timestamp]`.

Comment: IIRC one of them is in seconds, the other in milliseconds. So you need to divide by or multiple by 1000. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29243060/trying-to-convert-firebase-timestamp-to-nsdate-in-swift

Comment: `NSTimeInterval` is a floating-point value where the whole numbers represent whole seconds, so don't cast to `NSInteger`.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I divided it by 1000 as mentioned.

Comment: Ah right... I forgot to scroll right. :-) `FIRServerValue timestamp]` is not convertible to a timestamp like that. It's not an actual timestamp, but a dictionary that tells the Database **Server** to write the current timestamp. Kat's answer to the question I linked shows how to write to the server and then get the actual timestamp back in the client.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen So can't we get the current timestamp from server? I need to get current timestamp from the server without writing it on server.

Comment: That is not possible. You can approximate it with the approach described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43203910/how-to-create-negative-firebase-timestamp-in-swift/43394905#43394905 But it will be an approximation, it may be close - but it may also be off by a lot.