# How to get the timestamp from servervalue?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, server, timestamp

I'm trying to get the server time from the firebase with the following code:

```
let timestamp = ServerValue.timestamp()
let today = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: timestamp/1000)
```

But this gives me an error saying:

> Binary operator '/' cannot be applied to operands of type '[Any Hashable: Any]' and 'Int'

Why `ServerValue.timestamp()` dosen't return a TimeIntervel value?
How can I get the server's local time?

Comment: Whats is server value ? Can you share it ?

Comment: As per your error it's may be dictionary. right ?

Comment: Take a look to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29243060/trying-to-convert-firebase-timestamp-to-nsdate-in-swift

Comment: @Adolfo I already read this before I posted. But that question was posted two years ago, and I tried the solutions.

Comment: You’ll need to pull it out of the dictionary before you can operate on it. We need to see the actual return value of `ServerValue.timestamp()` to show you want you need to do exactly.

Comment: The link @Adolfo provided above is a great link and contains almost the exact code you need to write a Firebase timestamp. The only thing to add would be the code to observe the node the timestamp was written to. I just copy and pasted that code into a project and it worked perfectly. You may also want to see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43203910/how-to-create-negative-firebase-timestamp-in-swift/43379902#43379902) which is not directly related but may provide some additional insight into timestamps and Firebase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use the `ServerValue.TIMESTAMP` to get the Firebase's server time.

It maps to the Firestore timestamp value for the server time when you write it to a document.

If you want the server time, there are two ways.

1. Write the `ServerValue.TIMESTAMP` to a temporary doc in Firestore and read it from there.
2. Use a Google Cloud function to get an instance of `Date()` object as a string in `response.end()` method. Create an HTTP endpoint like this. You can then use an AJAX request to get the result.

`const app = (req, res) => {
    // this will return the Firebase server time
    res.send(new Date());
};`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to get the timestamp from servervalue but the error is being thrown because the `convenience init(timeIntervalSince1970 secs: TimeInterval)` you are using to create the date is expecting the secs to be in TimeInterval which is Double and to pass that you are trying to divide a type which is not permitted (timestamp/1000).

Below is an example of how your double value should be to get it working

```
let unixTimestamp = 1480134638.0
let date = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: unixTimestamp)

print(date) -> "2016-11-26 04:30:38 +0000\n"
```

Comment: Unfortunately this information has nothing to do with the question or the error; that error is indicating the division symbol '/' cannot be used on a Dictionary [Any Hashable: Any] divided by an Int. However, your comment about Double is on point.